Chrome Extension - Modify WSS request headers
I am using manifest v3 in my extension. Currently I'm trying to modify WSS request headers with declarative_net_request.
My rule looks like this:
{
    "id": 2,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "requestHeaders": [{ "header": "origin", "operation": "set", "value": "" }]
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "||mywebsite.com",
      "resourceTypes": ["websocket"]
    }
  }

This does not change the request headers, but another rule, for xmlhttprequest works as expected.
Any possible solutions to this problem?

It's a bug in Chrome, there's no workaround.
